# Not able to view newly created files inside docker

Tags: docker, flask

I have a flask app which is creating a json file via REST call. When I run it via docker, I am able to view the newly created file in the physical file system. 
But when I run a shell inside docker by

`sudo docker run -it <image> /bin/sh`,

then the file is not listed in the specific folder.

Docker run command:

```
sudo docker run -i -v $PWD/cw_rules/signals/signals_oas3.0:/cw_rules/signals/signals_oas3.0 -e PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 -p 5000:5000 img_name
```

Comment: With `docker run` you are starting a new container. You need a shell to the existing container. Try `docker exec container_id sh`.

Comment: The shell to the existing container is via  sudo docker run -it <image> /bin/sh. But the file is not listed when I cd to that folder.

Comment: Where do you save this .json file? Are they on `signals_oas3.0` folder? Because this is the only folder you are mounting as a volume. If the file is on another folder, you should volume mount this folder on your command as well.

Comment: Yes, the json file is saved inside signals_oas3.0. And I can view it in the physical system. But inside docker shell, it is not listed. Is it because at the time of building the docker image, the file was not present. It got added only on docker run.